# swift обновить высоту ячейки tableview

Tags: swift

У меня есть `tableview` с динамической высотой ячеек (высота ячейки зависит от `label`), все работает ок, но есть один момент :

если текст для `label` я подгружаю на сразу, а спустя некоторое время, то высота ячейки не изменяется, как это можно исправить ? пытался делать setNeedsLayout/layoutIfNeeded - не помогло

```
  class ParcelInfoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func data(infoDes: String) {
        getTranslate(infoDes: infoDes, organization: organization, place: place) { (_text) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.infoLabel.attributedText = _text
                self.setNeedsLayout()
                self.updateConstraints()
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте переопределить метод tableView и использовать UITableView.automaticDimension:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Comment: я так и делаю, если в методе data сразу ставить значение для infoLabel, то считает высоту нормально, но метод getTranslate выполняет post запрос в другом потоке и текст для infoLabel приходит не сразу и в этом случае высота не пересчитывается при присвоении нового текста для infoLabel

Comment: Возможно, Вам нужно добавить tableView.reloadData() после получения данных в фоне.

Comment: а есть способ изнутри ячейки обновить ? тк у меня все действия внутри ячейки происходят, а не в vc

Comment: Нужно сделать vc делегатом ячейки и в ячейке дернуть метод делегата

Comment: спасибо, только сделал через beginUpdates